# php: oop issues. likely very basic

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Hey, I was following through a tutorial and was trying to simplify it to my needs. I cant get anything to work.. if unsure, some debugging tips would be great!

Here is the class.php file:

```
class MySQL{

  public static function connect($set_host, $set_username, $set_password, $set_database){

    mysql_connect("$set_host", "$set_username", "$set_password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$set_database")or die("cannot select DB");

  }
}

class Posts {  

  public $id;  
  public $title;   

  function __construct($_id, $_title){  

    $this->id = $_id;  
    $this->title = $_title;

  }
}


class Generate {

  function queryPosts(){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC");

    $postArray = array();  
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){  

      $posts = new Posts($row["id"], $row['title']);  
      array_push($postArray, $posts);

    }     
    return $postArray;  
  }  
}
```

and here is the index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>dev</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php  
include ("class.php");  

MySQL::connect('localhost', 'test', 'pass', 'table');  

$blog = Generate();

foreach ($blog as $post)  
{  
    echo $post->title . "<br/>";  
}  
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

I really cant get anything to generate with this method. The table/data is there, and I can display them in a procedural manner.. however I am trying to get into oop methods of doing this. Knowing me it's probably a really silly syntax error. Many thanks!

Comment: does it return a result from the database query

Answer (score 4):

You're not using the new keyword, and then you're trying to iterate on $blog which is an object. You need to call the object's method, queryPosts, and iterate over it's results.

```
...
$blog = new Generate();
$posts = $blog->queryPosts();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be instantiating Generate with `new`:

```
$blog = new Generate;

foreach($blog->queryPosts() as $postArray){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing why are you putting " before and after the variable. It should be:
mysql_connect($set_host, $set_username, $set_password) or die("...");

Answer (score 0):

As you may already know, @David's answer solves the problem quite well, however, since you said you were following a tutorial, I want to make you some recomendations so you don't go down into PHP's dark path.

- You should consider putting different classes in different files
- Having a Class to connect directly to the database is not that good, try to connect to the database on the `queryPosts` method and not in the index.php file
- For starting purpouses, implementing data access like this will get you around the problem, but if you start working on more professionally oriented apps, consider using a ORM framework for data access, like [Propel](http://propelorm.org) or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

Hope I can help!